FullCalendar API keeps on creating multiple instances after a Receive Event instead of one, react
I tried to create a calendar in which from a nearby container you can drop no necessarily events but rather people to create for them events. After implementing the update function of any event works wonders, but when after a Receive event it creates multiple instances of the same event but with different IDs , at first it creates 3 then 4,5 and so on but if i interact and update one of the events the next Receive event wont respect this formula, but rather it will count how many updates have been made and add it to the next time the Receive event is called so basically if i am at 3 created instances, it should the next time create 4 but if i modify one of the 3 newly created the next amount of instances will be 5 not 4 and yeah if i move that event multiple times instead of 4 times it will create 4 + how many times i've edited anything and create those instances, and it will continue from that number upwords like from 5,6  and so on if there havent been any updates in terms of time or day(EventResizing,EventDrop)
const Calendar = ({ ToSaveEvents, uid, ToSaveEventsList }: any) => {

  const [events, setEvents] = useState<TrueCalendarEvent[]>([])
  const CalRef = useRef<FullCalendar>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const db = getDatabase(app)
    const unsub = onValue(ref(db, `users/${uid}/CalendarEvents`), (snapshot) => {
       ///getting any already saved events that may be changed or just for display
      }
    })

    return () => {
      unsub()
    }
  }, [])


  const InCalendarUpdate = useCallback((info: EventResizeDoneArg | EventDropArg) => {

    const { event } = info
    if (events.find(ev => ev.id === event.id)) {
      const db = getDatabase(app)
      remove(ref(db, `users/${uid}/CalendarEvents/${event.id}`))
      ToSaveEvents((prevEvents: any) => {
        return [...prevEvents, event]
      })
    }
    const updatedEvent = {
      title: info.event.title,
      start: info.event.start ? info.event.start.toISOString() : null,
      end: info.event.end ? info.event.end.toISOString() : null,
      color: "#D7C627"
    }

    //const {title,start,end,color,id} = lastev
    ToSaveEvents((prevEvents: any) => {
      return prevEvents.map((ev: TrueCalendarEvent) => {
        const { extendedProps, ...lastev } = ev
        return ev.id == event.id ? { ...lastev, ...updatedEvent, extendedProps: { ...extendedProps, lastevent: (extendedProps.lastevent == null ? lastev : extendedProps.lastevent) } } : ev
      })
    })


    info.event.remove();
  },[])

  const handleEventReceive =  useCallback((info: EventReceiveArg) => {

    const defaultEndTime = new Date(info.event.start!.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString()

    const newEvent = {
      id: info.event.id,
      title: info.event.title,
      start: info.event.start ? info.event.start.toISOString() : null,
      end: info.event.end ? info.event.end.toISOString() : defaultEndTime,
      color: "#D7C627",
      extendedProps: { lastevent: null, ToID: info.event.extendedProps.ToID }
    };

    // Append the event to the database and get the generated key
    ToSaveEvents((prevState: any) => {
      return [...prevState, newEvent]
    })

    // Remove the external event from the DOM
    info.event.remove();
  },[])


  useEffect(() => {

    if (CalRef.current) {
      const Calapi = CalRef.current.getApi()


      Calapi.setOption("eventReceive", undefined)
      Calapi.setOption("eventResize", undefined)
      Calapi.setOption("eventDrop", undefined)


      Calapi.setOption("eventReceive", handleEventReceive)
      Calapi.setOption("eventResize", InCalendarUpdate)
      Calapi.setOption("eventDrop", InCalendarUpdate)
    }
  }, [InCalendarUpdate,handleEventReceive])

  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      initialView="timeGridDay"
      events={[...events, ...ToSaveEventsList]}
      editable={true}
      droppable={true}
      headerToolbar={{ left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth' }}
      ref={CalRef}
    />
  );
};

This is the calendar component.
const SidebarDoctor = ({ uid }: any) => {
  const [users, changeUsers] = useState<any>([])

  const [doctorfirstname, changedoctorfirstname] = useState<string>("")
  const [doctorlastname, changedoctorlastname] = useState<string>("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const db = getDatabase(app)
    const fetchname = async () => {
          ///some call to the firebase database
    }
    fetchname()

    const unsub = onValue(ref(db, `users/${uid}/notifs`), async (snapshot: any) => {
        ///some call to the firebase database

    })
    return () => {
      unsub()
    }
  }, [])

  const UsersRef = useRef(null)

  const DragableElements = UsersRef.current
  if (DragableElements) {
    new Draggable(DragableElements,
      {
        itemSelector: '.user-item',
        eventData(eventEl) {
          const id = uuidv4()
          const firstlastnamePacient = eventEl.dataset.firstname + " " + eventEl.dataset.lastname
          const firstlastnameDoctor = doctorfirstname + " " + doctorlastname
          const lastevent: CalendarEvent = {
            id: "",
            title: "",
            start: "",
            end: "",
            color: ""
          }
          const ToID = eventEl.dataset.id
          return {
            id,
            title: firstlastnamePacient + " appointment to " + firstlastnameDoctor,
            extendedProps: { lastevent, ToID: ToID }
          };
        },
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div id="users-list" ref={UsersRef}>
        <h4>Users</h4>
        {users.map((user: any) => {
          return <div
            key={uuidv4()}
            data-id={user.id}
            style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}
            className="user-item fc-event"
          > {user.firstname + " " + user.lastname} </div>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>)
}

This is the container from which i can drag.
At everytime they are both next to each other
Demonstration: https://youtu.be/N5e6ezPjTPM

guys dont be like me and put the instance of draggable in a useEffect to not recreate a new instance every time it rerenders, now it works as it should.
  useEffect(()=>{
      const DragableElements = UsersRef.current
  if (DragableElements) {
    new Draggable(DragableElements,
      {
        itemSelector: '.user-item',
        eventData(eventEl) {
          const id = uuidv4()
          const firstlastnamePacient = eventEl.dataset.firstname + " " + eventEl.dataset.lastname
          const firstlastnameDoctor = doctorfirstname + " " + doctorlastname
          const lastevent: CalendarEvent = {
            id: "",
            title: "",
            start: "",
            end: "",
            color: ""
          }
          const ToID = eventEl.dataset.id
          return {
            id,
            title: firstlastnamePacient + " appointment to " + firstlastnameDoctor,
            extendedProps: { lastevent, ToID: ToID }
          };
        },
      });
  }
  },[])

